# accel-ppp add Domain-Name RADIUS attribute in Access-Request packets

Tags: radius

Anyone here has experience in accel-ppp. My goal is I want to include the Domain-Name RADIUS attribute in User-Name attribute when accel-ppp sends Access-Request packets to RADIUS server. Example, User-Name@Domain-Name, anyone here tried same thing?

Thanks.